# BIOS screen hangs

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios

When I start up my PC the BIOS splash screen appears and then hangs:
[image]
When I then pres Del, the BIOS POST screen appears but also hangs:
[image]
And I cannot get past these two screens.

I have already tried:

- Removing and reinserting CMOS battery
- Removing all USB devices
- Removing external graphics card and using onboard card
- Unplugging HD SATA cable

Has anyone experienced this before or have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you overclocking the CPU or RAM at all?  Sometimes a failed overclock will be stable enough to pass a POST but not stable enough to run the system.

Comment: No overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the video card and it does the same it may not be the easy way out (PSU problem).

If you have multiple RAM modules, remove all but one and try again.

If you have only 1, burrow a different one and try to boot-up, but try removing it and dust-cleaning it first.

Also, check CPU temperature (finger method, make sure heat-sink doesn't burn).

Anyway, for test purpose, let the HDD and the video card disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I did the RAM checks now but no difference, and the temperatures all feel fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this a few times. Assu machines have a built in safety in the megatrends BIOS to prevent bootup if a serious problem has appeared. From the look of the motherboard being at least 8 years old it may be a flat CMOS C2032 battery just needs replacing.

But if this doesnt work then it will more than likely be a failed hard drive or a lost boot block or MFT.

Try booting the computer if it will let you access the settings to boot from CD and use a windows CD to try the repair method to get the drive working again. Usually if a computer hangs it is because it fails to detect fully either a hard drive or CD drive or other attached component. The BIOS should contain information on the current health of the system and a look should tell you if anythings overheating.

On a machine of this age a good clean out with a Horse hair 1/2" paint brush would be a good idea to get all the dust away from the contacts and fans, especially the power supply

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to replace the CMOS battery first. Unfortunately I can't even boot from the CD. I tried unplugging the CD ROM and now the BIOS screen doen't even want to appear, even after plugging the CD ROM back in.

Comment: I am noticing something odd. If I remove the CMOS bettery, there is no connectivity between the two battery connections, surely this must not be so?